# MySQL join 4 tables with CASE

Tags: mysql, join, case

I would greatly appreciate some help developing a query structure that joins 4 tables but also includes multiple CASE statements as well.

I am attempting to generate a SELECT statement that I can use for quick-view reports on a client's website, which is pulling from the member directory and will show values of custom profile fields depending on the value I input.

**Here is my database structure (sanitized extract).**

```
--
-- Table structure for TABLE cats
--

CREATE TABLE cats (
cat_id INT(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
cat_name VARCHAR(64),
cat_parent INT(12),
primary KEY (cat_id));

--
-- Dumping data for TABLE cats
--
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(1, 'Root',  0);
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(2, 'GroupA', 1);
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(3, 'GroupB', 1);
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(4, 'ClassA', 2);
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(5, 'ClassB', 2);
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(6, 'ClassC', 2);
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(7, 'ClassD', 3);
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(8, 'ClassE', 3);
INSERT INTO cats VALUES(9, 'ClassF', 3);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for TABLE catlink
--

CREATE TABLE catlink (
 cl_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 link_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 cat_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
primary KEY (cl_id));


--
-- Dumping data for TABLE catlink
--

INSERT INTO catlink VALUES(1, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO catlink VALUES(2, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO catlink VALUES(3, 3, 5);
INSERT INTO catlink VALUES(4, 4, 6);
INSERT INTO catlink VALUES(5, 5, 7);
INSERT INTO catlink VALUES(6, 6, 8);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for TABLE links
--

CREATE TABLE links (
 link_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 link_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
primary KEY (link_id));

--
-- Dumping data for TABLE links
--


INSERT INTO links VALUES(1, 'Link One');
INSERT INTO links VALUES(2, 'Link Two');
INSERT INTO links VALUES(3, 'Link Three');
INSERT INTO links VALUES(4, 'Link Four');
INSERT INTO links VALUES(5, 'Link Five');
INSERT INTO links VALUES(6, 'Link Six');

-- -------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for TABLE cfvalues
--

CREATE TABLE cfvalues (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 cf_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 link_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 value mediumtext NOT NULL,
primary KEY (id));
--
-- Dumping data for TABLE cfvalues
--

INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(1, 54, 1, 'Link One name');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(2, 54, 2, 'Link Two name');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(3, 54, 3, 'Link Three name');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(4, 54, 4, 'Link Four name');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(5, 54, 5, 'Link Five name');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(6, 54, 6, 'Link Six name');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(7, 54, 7, 'Link Seven name');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(8, 54, 8, 'Link Eight name');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(9, 55, 1, 'Link One custom value');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(10, 55, 2, 'Link Two custom value');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(11, 55, 3, 'Link Three custom value');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(12, 55, 4, 'Link Four custom value');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(13, 55, 5, 'Link Five custom value');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(14, 55, 6, 'Link Six custom value');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(15, 55, 7, 'Link Seven custom value');
INSERT INTO cfvalues VALUES(16, 55, 8, 'Link Eight custom value');
```

**And here is my (totally not working) query.**

```
Select cats.cat_name, links.link_name, cfvalues.value 
MAX(CASE WHEN cfvalues.cf_id =54 THEN cfvalues.value END ) Name,
MAX(CASE WHEN cfvalues.cf_id =55 THEN cfvalues.value END ) Custom,
FROM cfvalues
INNER JOIN links ON links.link_id = cfvalues.link_id 
INNER JOIN catlink ON links.link_id = catlink.link_id
INNER JOIN cats ON cats.cat_id = catlink.cat_id
GROUP BY cfvalues.link_id;
```

**This is what I'm getting:**

```
| CAT_NAME |  LINK_NAME |           VALUE |
|----------|------------|-----------------|
|   ClassA |   Link One |   Link One name |
|   ClassB |   Link Two |   Link Two name |
|   ClassC | Link Three | Link Three name |
|   ClassD |  Link Four |  Link Four name |
|   ClassE |  Link Five |  Link Five name |
|   ClassF |   Link Six |   Link Six name |
```

**This is what I'm going for:**

```
| CAT_NAME |  LINK_NAME |            NAME |                  CUSTOM |
|----------|------------|-----------------|-------------------------|
|   ClassA |   Link One |   Link One name |   Link One custom value |
|   ClassB |   Link Two |   Link Two name |   Link Two custom value |
|   ClassC | Link Three | Link Three name | Link Three custom value |
|   ClassD |  Link Four |  Link Four name |  Link Four custom value |
|   ClassE |  Link Five |  Link Five name |  Link Five custom value |
|   ClassF |   Link Six |   Link Six name |   Link Six custom value |
```

Please note the column names would also need to update in the query so the results can be exported to CSV with unique column headers instead of value, value, value, etc.

Any suggestions? I do not claim to be a developer so I appreciate any help I can get!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution using a subquery:

```
select 
    c.cat_name,
    l.link_name,
    (select value from cfvalues cfv where cfv.link_id=l.link_id and cfv.cf_id=54) as name,
    (select value from cfvalues cfv where cfv.link_id=l.link_id and cfv.cf_id=55) as custom
from 
    cats c
    INNER JOIN catlink cl ON c.cat_id = cl.cat_id
    INNER JOIN links l ON l.link_id = cl.link_id
```

alternative using an if statement:

```
select 
    c.cat_name,
    l.link_name,
    max(if(cfv.cf_id=54, cfv.value, '')) as name,
    max(if(cfv.cf_id=55, cfv.value, ''))  as custom
from 
    cats c
    INNER JOIN catlink cl ON c.cat_id = cl.cat_id
    INNER JOIN links l ON l.link_id = cl.link_id 
    INNER JOIN cfvalues cfv ON cfv.link_id = l.link_id
group by c.cat_id, l.link_id
```

alternative using case:

```
select 
    c.cat_name,
    l.link_name,
    max(case cfv.cf_id when 54 then cfv.value else '' end) as name,
    max(case cfv.cf_id when 55 then cfv.value else '' end)  as custom
from 
    cats c
    INNER JOIN catlink cl ON c.cat_id = cl.cat_id
    INNER JOIN links l ON l.link_id = cl.link_id 
    INNER JOIN cfvalues cfv ON cfv.link_id = l.link_id
group by c.cat_id, l.link_id
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the 3 different alternatives! The last one using case is just what I need, but will keep the others for reference! Thanks again!

Comment: Can you check the green check mark next to my answer? Glad I could help!